# How to set PATH envirnment variable through a shell script though that shell script gets terminated?

Tags: linux

I am having a shell script `./my_shellscript.sh`, its contents are as follows :

```
source /path/to/shell_script.sh
```

Where `shell_script.sh` contains:

```
export PATH=/path/to/a/dir:$PATH
which command_name
```

when I execute the `my_shellscript.sh` then it shows accurate path to a command, that I executed using "which" command?

When the `shell_script.sh` terminates and when I again do "which command_name" from command line it doesn't shows any path as it shown when I executed the scripts.

My question is that how to set/persist that path to environment variable [PATH:$PATH]  though shell_script.sh terminates?

Comment: Please split the questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how environments work, you can't change the parent environment. You can only change your environment, and (optionally) that of child processes to your process.

Answer (score 0):

You could run your `./my_shellscript.sh` with `source` (or `.`) to export it's variables to your current environment.

```
source my_shellscript.sh
```

or

```
. my_shellscript.sh
```

Other option to put the `PATH` variable extension into your `.profile` file in your home directory. (`/home/your_username/.profile`) That will be permanent.